# Bounds on Riemann Zeta type Function?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Given a sequence $a_n$ such that $\sum_{n\ge1} \dfrac{|a_n|}{n^s}$ is convergent for $s>0$. Given that $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{|a_n|}{n} < 1$, is it be possible to impose some sort of an upperbound for $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{|a_n|}{n^s}$ for $1>s>k>0$ for some fixed $k$?

Comment: Given an integer $m$, define a sequence $a_n=\cases{m{\rm\ if\ }n=m\cr 0{\rm \ else}}$. 
While $\sum_{n\ge 1}{a_n\over n}=1$, you could replace $m$ with $m-\epsilon$ if you really cared about strict inequality. 

Since $\sum_{n\ge 1} {a_n\over n^s}=m^{1-s}$ and $m$ was chosen arbitrarily, there is no upper bound.

Comment: [I deleted my earlier comment as it was based on a misreading of the desired range for $s$. BR's example/objection nails it in my opinion.]

Comment: I added my comment as an answer to keep the question from being bumped in the future.

Comment: @BR - Thanks! Yeah, I wasn't really sure how to "accept" your answer, since you answered my question in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an integer $m$, define a sequence $a_n$ to be $m$ at the $m$-th place and $0$ otherwise.
Then
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} {a_n\over n^s}=m^{1-s}$$
As any upper bound must work for all $m$, we see that no upper bound is possible for $s<1$.